# Why can I not catch the value of Gridview row?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

Here is my code. 
problem: When click om a row och on select the page is refreshing and i dont get the text in the lable17.text.

```
 protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow row = GridView1.SelectedRow;

    Label17.Text = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString() ;
}


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.style.cursor='Pointer';this.style.backgroundColor='Yellow'");

    }
}

protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];
    Label17.Text = "you selected" + row.Cells[2].Text;
}
```

Comment: ya its 17 i, wrote wrong at the begining

Comment: i have put BreakPoint on the GridView1_SelectedIndexExchanged and SelectedIndexExchanging. But nothing happen when i click, I dont even se what value lable17 has

Comment: that means your events not fire, do you have select button column? if not add  autogenerateselectbutton="True" to your grid in aspx page.

Comment: This is my grid definition

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
            AllowSorting="True"   CssClass="DDGridview" CellPadding="3" 
            RowStyle-BackColor="Blue" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" 
            BorderWidth="1px" onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
            onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound" 
            onselectedindexchanging="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging" >

Answer (score 0):

Is your `GridView` in an `UpdatePanel`? If not the entire Page will postback when you click on the Button. Also, make sure that if you are setting the `Text` of `Label17` in the `Page_Load` event that you only do it the first time i.e.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Label17.Text = "Default Text";
    }
}
```

Comment: how to make the page not refreshing ??

Comment: but i want the lable text i a selected cell, not " Default text".